# Код для поиска числа e не запускается

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int s=2;
double a,k=1,sum=1;
scanf("%lf",&a);
do{
    sum=sum+k;
    k=k*(1/s);
    s++;
}while (a<k);
printf("%.8lf",sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Небольшой код, Вычислить число e=1+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+...+1/k! и так пока следующее слагаемое не станет меньше а

Не понимаю в чем ошибка?

Comment: Пройдите отладчиком по шагам. Например, чему равно 1/s при целом s?

Comment: У вас s в начале кода равно 2, а вы пишете должно быть e=1+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+...+1/k => получается 1 + 1/2!! + 1/3 и т.д. Вы не получите 1 + 1/1

Comment: @Стас, там еще и `k` используется, которое как раз `1` равно вначале

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените одну строку:

```
k=k*(1/s);
```

на

```
k=k/s;
```

Когда вы пишите 1/s, то получаете 0, потому что и 1, и `s` имеют тип `int`, и деление получается целочисленное. А так как `s` больше 1, то и в результате - 0.

Comment: Еще лучше `sum += k /= s++`...

Comment: вот за такой код нужно сразу вон из профессии.

Comment: @KoVadim Вы не написали, кому - мне или Harry?

Comment: очевидно, что Harry. А в Вашем ответе не хватает только маленького комментария, который объясняет, что именно происходит.

Comment: @KoVadim Просто вы не указали получателя :) Комментарий я дописал.

Comment: @Mikhailo ну почти. Можно было бы ещё дописать, что при целочисленном делении, если делимое больше делителя, всегда будет ноль. А в нашем случае s будет больше 1. Как  то так